# Is key necessary in MapReduce?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

In my case I do not need a reduce function. So I am assuming that the map function should not worry about choosing and splitting the input text file to some key-value pair.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does. Mappers always output a key,value pair. If you don't want to use a reducer, you can write Map output directly to file system, or you can use an Identity Reducer. If you're not Interested in what the key is, you can maybe just assign some default key. If you can share some more details about what you're trying to do, we can probably help you out better.

Comment: @Chaos- Have a look at this question. It would be a great help if you can suggest something. [Problem Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17600258/how-to-select-the-optimal-key-in-map-reduce)

Comment: @udag , yes checking it out